# La variable hora se me cambia cuando se inserta en la base de datos - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time

tengo una variable '@hs' que contiene la hora en el siguiente formato:

> 2000-01-01 09:00:00 -0300

El problema es cuando hago un Mitabla.new(:hs => @hs) me inserta esa hora pero diferida, es decir en vez de insertarme la hora 09:00:00 me inserta tres horas mas siempre, 12:00:00.
Yo antes de insertarla en mi base de datos la muestra para saber si esta bien y me la trae bien con la hora que debe ser, se modifica al insertarse. Alguna solucion?

Comment: Intenta configurar la zona horaria en tu servidor en la seccion de MySQL

Comment: ¿La base de datos es MySQL?

Comment: Cuando lees el registro de vuelta en tu aplicación, muestra la hora correcta? Que base de datos estas utilizando? Como o con que software estas accediendo a la base de datos para verificar el valor?

Comment: La BD es en postgresql. Cuando realizo un nombredelatabla.all para ver los registros insertados me figura con la hora diferida '+3 hs', pero antes de insertarlo tengo el valor en una variable y la muestro para saber si realmente esta bien el valor que deseo insertar y efectivamente esta bien antes de insertar

Answer (score 1):

Debes especificar la zona horaria para la aplicación y para `ActiveRecord`, así garantizas que siempre estarán en sincronía. Esto lo puedes lorgar editando el archivo *config/application.rb*; ejemplo:

```
class Application < Rails::Application
  # otras configuraciones ...

  config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
  config.time_zone = "Mexico City"
end
```

Comment: Si, de esa manera lo tengo hecho: 
# Set zone
    config.time_zone = 'Buenos Aires'
    config.active_record.default_timezone = :local

Comment: ¿Reiniciaste tu aplicación después del cmabio?, ¿qué fecha tiene tu base de datos?

Comment: Si, reinicie todo. Hay algún comando por rails console para que pueda obtener la fecha de la base?